# Class in jar not found at runtime, but was used to compile

Tags: java, ant, runtime, java-3d, compile-time

After I build this project from an ant file, I recieve a jar that contains all of the classes I built. When I try to run this jar, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/SceneGraphObject
```

This error indicates that a one of the jars, specifically the `j3dcore.jar` from java3d, I am using can not be found. However, this jar is on the classpath when compiling through the ant build into the class files.

Why can this class not be found at runtime, but it is found at compile time? Do I have to manually change my classpath in my shell when running the jar as well as change it in the ant build?

If I add the jars to my classpath using `java -cp j3d/*.jar  -jar idv.jar`

I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class j3d.j3dutils.jar`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do I have to manually change my classpath in my shell when running the jar as well as change it in the ant build?

Yes, absolutely. Making a class available at compile-time doesn't embed the class into your output or anything like that. It just makes it available to the compiler (to find out what methods are present etc).

> If I add the jars to my classpath using java -cp j3d/*.jar -jar idv.jar

Yes, it would - because that's being expanded into:

```
java -cp j3d/foo.jar j3d/bar.jar ... -jar idv.jar
```

It's not clear to me whether `-cp` is meant to work at all with `-jar`, given [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html):

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

One option is to [set the classpath within the manifest of the jar file itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). For example:

```
Class-Path: j3d/foo.jar j3d/bar.jar
```

Another would be to ignore the `-jar` command-line option for now, and use:

```
java -cp j3d/*:idv.jar your.class.name.Here
```

Note the `*` rather than `*.jar`, as documented:

> As a special convenience, a class path element containing a basename of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR (a java program cannot tell the difference between the two invocations).

Comment: Thanks for a very easy to read and understand answer Jon. All is working.

Comment: *"It's not clear to me whether -cp is meant to work at all with -jar"*.  In fact, it doesn't work.  If you use `--jar`, the `java` command will *silently* ignore both `-cp` and `$CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @StephenC: Right - that's what I'd expected (other than the silently part, for `-cp`) but didn't want to be too forthright. It seems to me that it really should complain if you specify both `-cp` and `-jar`...

Comment: "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored." - this is a VERY useful piece of information which made me lose half a day today. Thank you!