# Jar dependency can't be found in run-time

Tags: java, json, jar, dependencies, gson

I'm trying to compile a jar file with my java program using 
`javac -cp dependency.jar *.java` and then run it using `java -cp dependency.jar mainPrgram` 
The program compiles just fine, and also runs fine, until a function call is made using the dependency.

Exception I get is below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
        at DFS.readMetaData(DFS.java:250)
        at DFS.touch(DFS.java:111)
        at CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:41)
        at CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 4 more
```

Tried different solutions from

[Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

[Class in jar not found at runtime, but was used to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561622/class-in-jar-not-found-at-runtime-but-was-used-to-compile)

But none seemed to work

**UPDATE:** The code runs fine within Eclipse, but not from the command line

After running it with eclipse, `.classpath` has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/MyPC/Documents/projects/MusicPlayer/gson-2.8.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Eclipse adds transient dependencies to the class path when it starts the application. You should be able to see the command line used by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yor program is successfully completed against the jar. But the jar itself has a dependency that is required to run. You need to add all dependencies to the class path, like `java -cp dependency.jar:subdependency.jar Main`.

Comment: From my understanding, I don't need any sub-dependencies, only this jar file.